# Why does Elixir not have guard clauses within a function?

Tags: functional-programming, elixir

Why does Elixir have guard clauses for function definition in the module and not in function itself? I find the following to be more intuitive:

```
def fibonnaci(n) do
  when n == 0, do: 0
  when n == 1, do: 1
  when n > 1 do
    fibonnaci(n - 2) + fibonnaci(n - 1)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if this is a question about how to write that code or about why the language was designed like that. Assuming it is the first, you have:

```
def fibonnaci(0), do: 0
def fibonnaci(1), do: 1
def fibonnaci(n), do: fibonnaci(n - 2) + fibonnaci(n - 1)
```

In case you want everything in the same function body, you could use a case:

```
def fibonnaci(n) do
  case n do
    0 -> ...
```

If you meant the latter, the answer may become clearer once you get more familiar with the language because the proposed example is not valid syntax (Elixir relies on a simple syntax with very few keywords where everything abides to the same rules).

Comment: I did mean the latter, why the choice was made to have the guard clause in the module instead of inside the function body. Thanks for answering, looking forward to digging deeper into the language and understanding the rationale behind the choice.